# Creating a list depending on the values in a matrix in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I am looking for the solution for the following problem. I have a matrix, where a number is filled in whenever the item on the x-axis and y-axis are connected. Since the matrix changes over time, the numbers are not sorted. My goal is to create a line item (on a different tab) whenever a number is entered in the matrix. The line item should contain the number itself and the name of the items on both axes. See example. I fill the first table and want the second table to be automatically generated based on the first table. The numbers don't need to be in ascending order, rather in the order of the first table, going left to right and then down.

I tried a bunch of stuff, using match and index, but it appears not to be working with a matrix.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Since the matrix changes over time, the list of items will change - new items to be appended? Formulas will not work and my recommendation is that you'll need a VBA solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the numbers you could use this formula and drag down up to the row that you need:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($B$2:$D$4,ROWS($F$2:F2)),"")
```

[image]

On the other hand, to extract the X and Y values you could use two array formulas and drag down as you need it (don't forget to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in order to works correctly):

**X value**

```
=IF(F2<>"",INDEX($A$1:$D$1,MAX(IF(F2=$B$2:$D$4,COLUMN($B$2:$D$4),""))),"")
```

[image]

**Y value**

```
=IF(F2<>"",INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MAX(IF(F2=$B$2:$D$4,ROW($B$2:$D$4),""))),"")
```

[image]

The brackets at the beginning and the end of the formula are because are array formulas.

[You can find an example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RIaWR43D86DR-lAAgRVzYOkQC5MJKawm/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true) (download it as excel file to test it)

Comment: Very helpful Mario, thank you! I managed to get it working for my Excel sheet, but now I am facing a new challenge which I didn't realize before. In the righthand table I want to create an extra column, where I can add a comment for each line. Whenever a number is added to or removed from the lefthand table, this comment should of course stay in line with the same number. Any suggestions on how I could solve this?